# PHP headers and redirect and cloaking - How To Control What URL is shown in the address bar and what text is shown in the title bar of the window

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, web-deployment

I am creating a redirect for affiliate links on my website.

I have a database that is storing a unique hash and a destination url for each link so that I can map my redirects as shown below

```
mysite/links/uniquehash ---> destination_url
```

At present I am setting the php header() function with the location as the argument.

```
header("Location:" . $destinationUrl);
```

And it works as expected I was just wondering if I am able to control what URL is shown in the address bar and what text is shown in the title bar of the window?

I wanted to know if that can be done in PHP, or is this mainly done via JavaScript and loading or HTML frames?

Comment: The title is controlled by the <title> tag in the HTML of the page

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah thanks mat I kind of get that, I'm looking for a way to URL mask on the server side.